# Why compiler is complaining while variable is in the range of long data type

Tags: c#, types, compiler-errors, long-integer

I have following declaration in my class.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private const long SOME_VALUE= (10 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);  // 10 GB
    ....
}
```

However compiler is reporting following error

> error CS0220: The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx).

[image]

As far as I can tell, **SOME_VALUE** is in this range for **long** type. Any thoughts on why am I getting this compile time error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of the individual values in the calculation are `int` so the compiler multiplies them together as `int`s, hence the overflow. The easiest solution is to mark one or all of them as a `long` using the [`L` suffix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_0), this will force the calculation to be done as a `long`:

```
private const long SOME_VALUE= 10L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `L` suffix:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private const long SOME_VALUE= (10L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L);  // 10 GB
    ....
}
```

Without `L` suffix (stands for `long`) compiler treats the expression as of `int` one and warns about integer overflow.